# Set Breakpoint at Entry point fails (GDB)

Tags: x86, gdb, breakpoints, objdump

I'm currently practicing some RE w/ GDB and am having issues simply stopping the run/start on the first/second instruction.  I am new to GDB/RE and have a *limited* knowledge of some of GDB's inner workings.  So far when I open the program I have done:

```
(gdb) set disassembly-flavor intel
(gdb) file /path/to/binary
(gdb) info file
Symbols from "/path/to/binary".                                                                                                
Local exec file:                                                                                                          
    `/path/to/binary', file type elf32-i386.                                                                               
    Entry point: 0x8048450
    .
    .
    .
(gdb) b *0x8048450
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 2 at 0x80485f7                                                                                       
Starting program: /path/to/binary                                                                                              
During startup program exited with code 1.
```

Another attempt at the program also produced this result:

```
(gdb) b *0x8048450
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048450
(gdb) run
Starting program: /bomb/bomb                                                                                              
During startup program exited with code 1.
```

So clearly setting the breakpoint at the entry point is not useful.  Below is the output of the command :

```
 objdump /path/to/binary -M intel -D
```

At the preceeding memory address.

```
08048450 <_start>:
 8048450:       31 ed                   xor    ebp,ebp
 8048452:       5e                      pop    esi                                                                        
 8048453:       89 e1                   mov    ecx,esp                                                                    
 8048455:       83 e4 f0                and    esp,0xfffffff0                                                             
 8048458:       50                      push   eax                                                                        
 8048459:       54                      push   esp                                                                        
 804845a:       52                      push   edx                                                                        
 804845b:       68 c0 86 04 08          push   0x80486c0                                                                  
 8048460:       68 60 86 04 08          push   0x8048660                                                                  
 8048465:       51                      push   ecx                                                                        
 8048466:       56                      push   esi                                                                        
 8048467:       68 e9 85 04 08          push   0x80485e9                                                                  
 804846c:       e8 bf ff ff ff          call   8048430     <__libc_start_main@plt>                                            
 8048471:       f4                      hlt                                                                               
 8048472:       66 90                   xchg   ax,ax                                                                      
 8048474:       66 90                   xchg   ax,ax                                                                      
 8048476:       66 90                   xchg   ax,ax                                                                      
 8048478:       66 90                   xchg   ax,ax                                                                      
 804847a:       66 90                   xchg   ax,ax                                                                      
 804847c:       66 90                   xchg   ax,ax                                                                      
 804847e:       66 90                   xchg   ax,ax
```

My overall goal is to jump to a specific function in the program using the b *Mem, jump *Mem technique and execute the code w/in that function.  In order to do this however I need to be able to stop the program while it is running I believe.

Comment: What version of `gdb` and on which OS are you running?  What you have tried above should work fine, and, for me, with gdb 7.9.1, and a simple example, it does work fine, so there is something specific about your case that is causing problems.

Comment: From the gdb startup: GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1 
OS (lsb_release -a): Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: My guess is that you're exiting from the dynamic linker before reaching `_start` in your test binary.  Try `set environment LD_DEBUG=all` at the gdb prompt before starting your program, take a look at the output, it might offer some clues why you're not getting as far as the entry point of your binary.