# gdb exits on breakpoint hit android embedded Armv7

Tags: debugging, gdb, embedded-linux

i am using gdb to debug a multi-threaded process.when i set a breakpoint(anywhere,either a native file such as "system" or an internal function, it is set, but once the breakpoint is caught - the process exits with error 1:

```
(gdb) b*0xB6F532F5
Breakpoint 1 at 0xb6f532f5
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program exited with code 01.
```

this happends with any process on the system,the gdb is statically compiled, and the process is arm a7(thumb)

Thanks,

Comment: It looks like everything is working fine. You set up a breakpoint, and you reach it. Then you run continue and that way the program runs according to its logic and exists. In other words, you have to use next or step command once you are at the breakpoint.

Comment: Not exactly - i set the breakpoint - and once the BP catches it exits(notice i run c and never enter the BP...) - the BP is catched but causes exit.

Comment: I have to say that there are sometimes faulty gdb versions. Check your version and try Google or some other search  engine if you hit a known problem. Also, try to set another breakpoint before the place of the b*0xB6F532F5 and see what happens. One cannot be sure about the problem without some additional information.

Comment: I did - to be clear - Any breakpoint(either b read or b on a specific address) acts like this.As for the gdb version - tried 3 different versions - i'm considering compiling it on the device itself but doubt it will work.

Comment: There is a suggestion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086844/set-breakpoint-at-entry-point-fails-gdb?r=SearchResults

Comment: Thanks - does not affect though, i do notice that on syscal bp(for example: b read),  i get sigtrapped   (gdb) b read
Breakpoint 1 at 0xb6c8630c
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb)

Comment: Are you using a proper Android gdb built from AOSP sources?   Typically for android one uses *gdbserver* and the ndk-gdb (or AOSP equivalent) on the development machine.  Remember that **Android has its own libc and by extension dynamic linker**, so just throwing tools from some everyday toolchain at it is likely to cause lots of problems.